# Entity Framework 7 group by

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to run the following code but when I check the SQL profiler it looks like it runs a full select on the table and then does the grouping after it returns all results from the database.  Any help is appreciated.

```
 var result = _dbContext.LogEvent.GroupBy(x => x.EventLevel)
                                 .Select(g => new 
                                              { 
                                                  eventType = g.Key, 
                                                  total = g.Sum(i => i.Occurrences) 
                                              }) 
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL you see in the profiler?

Comment: It just does a "Select column1, column2, column3, column4 From LogEvent".  No grouping or sum in the SQL.

Comment: I'd expect to see that if you did something like `_dbContext.LogEvent.AsEnumerable()...` or `_dbContext.LogEvent.ToList()...` As your query is written, appropriate SQL should be generated. Can you try the following: 
`var query = = _dbContext.LogEvent.GroupBy(x => x.EventLevel).Select(g => new { eventType = g.Key, total = g.Sum(i => i.Occurrences) });

Debug.Write(query.ToString());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Updated:

The issue linked below has been closed, and it is slated for EF 2.1.0. You should be able to try it out now using the Preview package!

---

### Original answer:

[It doesn't look like this is currently supported](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341), but it looks like someone saw this post and created the linked issue.

The concept is a fairly complex bit of logic, and EF7 is very much in an early phase.  .Net's `GroupBy` doesn't translate directly to SQL's `GROUP BY` until you follow it up with only aggregates or the Key in a `Select`. If you're feeling ambitious, you could work on providing a pull request, or [continue to use EF6.](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/tsneed/when-should-you-make-the-move-to-entity-framework-7)

Comment: Yeah I didn't think it was done yet.  I was looking through the source code and there are some things commented out.  I can work around this issue for now.  Thanks.

Comment: Will be supported in EF Core 2.1: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/02/entity-framework-core-2-1-roadmap/

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not going to be supported any time soon - unfortunatelt. Going to cause a lot of frustration because so many people don't read release notes and would just naturally assume it would work as before (EF6 / Linq2SQL).

I realize it can be complex for more complicated things involving whole entities, but it's a shame it isn't even supported for simple queries like yours :-(

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-rc2/